# Linking a Jquery/html variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do, is I have an HTML textbox, that I want to grab what is entered in, and use it as a variable in my javascript file, do I use jquery or is there a way to just access whatever text is entered directly in the javascript code?

Comment: The answer is **You can** and **Yes**. Now clarifying the question with an example of your HTML may result in a more detailed example :) Note: a jQuery solution will typically be a lot shorter than raw JS.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do that with JavaScript without using frameworks like jQuery. Can you please provide the relevant code snippets.

Comment: Hi Cthulu Bot, if you feel like your question was fully answered, don't forget to mark an answer as "accepted" by using the gray checkmark next to the answer. If not, please tell us what else we can help with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML, give the input element an `id` like so:

```
<input type="text" id="myText">
```

Then in your javascript, to get the value, use:

```
var text = document.getElementById("myText").value;
```

This answer uses vanilla JavaScript rather than jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this. You should give an id to your HTML element or you can call it with its type. Create a variable, select the HTML element with jQuery selector and use val() method to grab its value:

```
var input = $('selector').val() ;
```

If you decide to use jQuery don't forget to add the jQuery library in your HTML's head tag:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can also look at val(), html(), and text() (to set a new value) methods in jQuery web [page](http://api.jquery.com/val/).